# XMLParsing problem

Tags: iphone

I display  List of date's on my table view....

based on the date's.. i need to search location. and title

"**with the help of url**".

example
String *url=@"http://compliantbox.com/party_temperature/djsearch.php?date=?"

for the selected date.

i appended the date value to the string url.

So i need to parse again same xml parser. with date search.

```
<root>
<event title="event_title"location="new york"date="12/01/2011"/>
<event title="event_title2"location="california"date="13/01/2011"/>
<event title="event_title3"location="new york"date="14/01/2011"/>
</root>
```

here  my array get's Re-Initialization.

so i get conflict. when displaying data....

I need to not re-Initialization my array again. and again...
I need to initialize my array only once in entire application.

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"root"]){
        dateListArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
}
```

I Hope you people understand my problem.
Please help me out .

@Thanks to All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that you should trying here,

```
if([dateListArray count] > 0)
{
    [dateListArray removeAllObjects];
    [dateListArray release];
}
  dateListArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And other way you should also be trying,

```
 dateListArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

above statement write down in `-(void)viewDidLoad` event and

```
if([dateListArray count] > 0)
{
    [dateListArray removeAllObjects];
}
```

above write down in your required function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess:

NSMutableArray:-removeAllObjects

may help~

Comment: if you removing all objects form the NSmutableArray it will removing all but allocation in memory of array will still remaining.

Comment: Yes,it does
So then it can use addObject:

er,...not sure

Comment: @kiran kumar, you not need to take one more array. If you using first part of your accepted question.